# Approaching the concurrency of medians via limiting the common section through which the medians necessarily needs to pass by

Tags: geometry

I was trying to attempt the proof of concurrency of the medians in a triangle. The idea that specifically hit me was to mark down a particular area through which the medians must necessarily pass and then to scale down that area to be precisely 0 as we shrink down the parameter . Maybe it is a sort of unnecessary approach , but just wanted to ask , can proceeding in such a way make sense , if yes , then can there be a more concrete and rigid proof for such an approach. However what the intuitive idea speaks is as described below :

We have to see that whether the meeting points of all the medians happen to be a same point. Let us see where can the meeting point of two medians lie , more specifically we could take some area where the meeting points of two medians must necessarily lie and then somehow limit down that area to a specific point , which would intuitively be the meeting point for those two medians , maybe it can be more formalised , but let us as of now believe it to be true. For example in one of the figures attached below , the median from A to the opposite side must necessarily pass through the area marked by the triangle with dotted lines, with A as a vertex and other two vertices lying at a distance $\epsilon$ from the midpoint of the facing side, i.e. BC.[image: Area for the median through A to reside]

Similarly the median through another vertex C must pass through the area marked through its dotted lines with the same $\epsilon$ distance about the midpoint of AB.[image: The region with the common area for two medians]

Now , the common area out of the two areas must be the limit to the area in which the meeting point of the two medians can lie. Similarly , there must be some limiting area for the intersection point of the median through the vertex B with the median through the other two corners. Would it be sufficient to prove that all these limiting areas go to a single point as the parameter $\epsilon$ goes to 0. And is it justified to choose the same parameter $\epsilon$ for scaling down all the limiting areas. And even if such argument might be sufficient , can it be attempted and formalised?[image: A deceptive ideal picture with all of the areas sort of overlapping with a common area which 'might' go to single point of concurrency]

At this point , I know I am overcomplicating such a question, and there are simple and nice proofs , but just had an intuition about can we construct some formal argument on these lines, or is it an unnecessary dead end with me asking improper questions ? I guess I might have conveyed what the intuition is , but am not able to judge , can such direction lead something about the problem and moreover I don't think I have encountered such tools with sort of vague application of scaling down the area and testing whether they all go to same point, I guess we could somehow bring coordinate geometry but I think that would make things pretty much messy.

Comment: I guess it doesn't make much sense , as the limiting of areas just tells us what the intersection points are and nothing more , maybe just complicating a simple problem, but still , I am interested in hearing what the viewpoint might be. Thanks

Comment: Reducing the *area* to be $0$ does not necessarily imply the figure becomes a single point. A line is a geometric figure with $0$ area, but uncountably many points. If you want to use this approach, you need to make the *diameter* of the set (i.e., the largest distance between any two points in the set) go to $0$. With that change, yes, this would work, though it would still be a very quixotic approach to the problem.

Comment: Ok, I will lookup for that , and quite random and impractical approach now I reflect :). Thanks